# custom meta box text field: how to limit to alpha or numeric only

Tags: custom-field

I created a custom meta text field for adding a body class to a specific page. I want to limit the text to only alpha characters.

Also, I am using https://github.com/webdevstudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress to create the meta box fields.

The field works, but I can enter any characters; eg, {),;. That won't work for a body class.

Thanks

Comment: Use `ctype_alnum` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php.  It will check for only alpha numeric; and return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some research on how and see if this works.

Comment: If you post some code on where you want to place this check; I'll see if I can help.  Basically; you want to take the variable containing the text you want to check; and pass it through the `ctype_alnum` function.  `if(ctype_alnum($data)===true) {echo 'success'} else {echo 'try again'}`

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. The Custom Meta Boxes and Fields plugin has a sanitize setting where you can add your own sanitize function or use one of the default wordpress sanitize functions. In my case, Wordpress already has a sanitize function that does exactly what I wanted. See the code below, specifically the line 
"'sanitization_cb' => 'sanitize_html_class',"

```
            array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom Body Class', 'cmb' ),
            'id'   => $prefix . 'wnd_bodyclass',
            'type' => 'text_medium',
            'sanitization_cb' => 'sanitize_html_class', // custom sanitization callback. see this page for details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field
        ),
            array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom Post Class', 'cmb' ),
            'id'   => $prefix . 'wnd_postclass',
            'type' => 'text_medium',
        ),
```